# Adding / Subtracting options of a box through a change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two select boxes. I'd like to populate the number of options of second select box based on the value inside the option the user chooses within the first select box. So for example the first select box has options (with values) ranging from 1-3. If the user selects the second option there should be 2 options in the second select box. If the third option is selected then there are three options. And if the first is selected there should be only one option.

I've managed to populate the second select box using a `change` event but what I'm trying to figure out how to remove excess options. So far its just appending options (as it should). So for example if I selected the third option and change back to the first, 2 & 3 should be removed.

**HTML**

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>  


<select></select>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $('select:eq(0)').on('change', function() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= $('select:eq(0) option:selected').val(); i++) {
      $('select(1)').append('<option val="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it using [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/):

```
$(function () {
    $('select:eq(0)').on('change', function () {
        $('select:eq(1)').empty();
        for (var i = 1; i <= $(this).val(); i++) {
            $('select:eq(1)').append('<option val="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

But you could do it like this too:

```
$(function () {
    $('select:eq(0)').on('change', function () {
        $('select:eq(1)').html($(this).find('option:selected').prevAll().addBack().clone());
    });
});
```

### -DEMO-

Regarding performance, i'd use that instead: {even thought using document fragment could be faster than string concatenation, really not sure about that...}

```
$(function () {
    var select1 = $('select')[1];
    $('select').eq(0).on('change', function () {
        for (var i = 1, z = this.value, str = ""; i <= z; i++) {
            str += '<option val="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
        }
        select1.innerHTML = str;
    });
});
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: Didn't know empty exists, I've always used `html("")` good point

Comment: Which of the two do you think is less expensive?

Comment: If performance matters, i'd say don't use any of them. I'll update answer with a more performant way.

Comment: I assumed that having to run a for-loop for each change event would've been more expensive but that's probably not the case here (referencing your third option)?

Comment: @CarlEdwards `prevAll()` is using internally a `while` loop, so there is still a loop there. Anyway, you cannot get all specific elements without looping in a way or an other. That's said, if you don't have thousand options to copy, just use the method you find the most readable

Comment: 1+ and thanks for such thorough examples and explanations for each.

Answer (score 0):

You could clear the inner html of the second select

```
$(function() {
  $('select:eq(0)').on('change', function() {
      $('select:eq(1)').html("");
    for (var i = 1; i <= $('select:eq(0) option:selected').val(); i++) {
        $('select:eq(1)').append('<option val="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
    }
  });
});
```